# How connect xenforo and WordPress using XenWord

Tags: wordpress, xenforo

I installed a fresh copy or **WordPress in my xampp**, path below

**http://localhost/office/wp/wordpress/**

I also install xenforo in forums folder, link here

**http://localhost/office/wp/wordpress/forums**

Both xenforo and WordPress  having separate databases.

I installed XenWord plugin  in WordPress and activated.

**But the problem is that how connect both wordpress and xenforo to each other**

Kindly tell me how we make setting to connect them to each other.

Comment: how can i make the absolute path ? xenforo installed in forums folder

Answer (score 0):

The absolute path is found through the phpinfo supplied with XenForo.

domain.com/community/admin.php?tools/phpinfo.php

Look for the SCRIPT_FILENAME and DOCUMENT_ROOT to give you information about the structure of your site.

Enter the absolute path to the XenForo installation.